# Trigonometrical functions

Tags: trigonometry

I've been trying to solve this for 1hour, but I can't do it. I don't know if I'm missing something or it just doesn't open to me...

Simplify the following expression:

$$\frac{\sin^2 x - \cos^2 x}{ \sin x - \cos x}$$

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Factor the numerator ($a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$).

Comment: Thank You, now it seems so obvious. I don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: Your welcome; glad to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's $\sin(x)+\cos(x)$. Follow Mitra's hint!

Answer (score 2):

It might further be [simplified](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28x%29%2Bcos%28x%29) to $\sqrt{2}\sin(x + \pi/4)$.